# Android storing image path in to SQLite DB

Tags: android, image, sqlite

I'm developing an application that intends to store the data in a SQLIte database. It's kind of a virtual city guide.
As so, I'm storing some text elements on the DB and I'd like to store the path of an image and a video stored in the device in different columns and tables of the DB.

Kind of:

```
_ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT (id of the image)
IMAGE_PATH TEXT UNIQUE (path of the image associated with the ID)
```

Can anyone give some examples on how can I do this?

Comment: What have you tried?  Showing an attempt at some code, or doing searches for examples shows that you've done you're homework

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer of Bill Gary works well for one image, but as I want to do a gallery I used the code below :

```
this.imgPath = new String[mImageCursor.getCount()];

        int i = 0;

        while (mImageCursor.moveToNext()) {
            imgName = mImageCursor.getString(mImageCursor.getColumnIndex(MyDbAdapter.IMAGE_PATH));
            Log.w(TAG, baseDir + imgName);
            this.imgPath[i] = baseDir + imgName;
            Log.w(TAG, baseDir + mImageCursor.getString(mImageCursor.getColumnIndex(MyDbAdapter.IMAGE_PATH)) + " After");
            i++;
        }

        Gallery gallery = (Gallery) findViewById(R.id.VGgallery);
        gallery.setAdapter(new MyImageAdapter(this, this.imgPath));
```

Hope it helps someone else.

Answer (score 0):

Store the path as text, tehn when you get it in your cursor(variable imagePath for example), use this ...

```
imageResource = this.getResources().getIdentifier(
                imagePath, null, null);
ImageView.setImageResource(imageResource);
```